# How do I update Spring Security?

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am trying to update an example I got from my java curse of Spring Security to the up-to-date one.
So far I was able to update the POM using Maven but I still get an Error about the WebMvcSecurityConfiguration which is deprecated and I can not figure out where it is called or used.
Here is the Error I get when running the programm:

```
APPLICATION FAILED TO START

Description:

An attempt was made to call a method that does not exist. The attempt was made from the following location:

    org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.
WebMvcSecurityConfiguration$HandlerMappingIntrospectorCachFilterFactoryBean.getObject(WebMvcSecurityConfiguration.java:183)

The following method did not exist:

    'jakarta.servlet.Filter org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.HandlerMappingIntrospector.createCacheFilter()'

The calling method's class, org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebMvcSecurityConfiguration
$HandlerMappingIntrospectorCachFilterFactoryBean, was loaded from the following location:

    jar:file:/C:/Users/USERNAME/.m2/repository/org/springframework/security/spring-security-
config/6.2.1/spring-security-config-6.2.1.jar!/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configuration
/WebMvcSecurityConfiguration$HandlerMappingIntrospectorCachFilterFactoryBean.class

The called method's class, org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.HandlerMappingIntrospector, is available from the following locations:

    jar:file:/C:/Users/USERNAME/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-webmvc/6.0.12/spring-
webmvc-6.0.12.jar!/org/springframework/web/servlet/handler/HandlerMappingIntrospector.class

The called method's class hierarchy was loaded from the following locations:

    org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.HandlerMappingIntrospector: file:/C:/Users/USERNAME/
.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-webmvc/6.0.12/spring-webmvc-6.0.12.jar


Action:

Correct the classpath of your application so that it contains compatible versions of the classes org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.
WebMvcSecurityConfiguration$HandlerMappingIntrospectorCachFilterFactoryBean and org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.HandlerMappingIntrospector


Process finished with exit code 1
```

Here is my POM:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.4</version>
        <relativePath/>
    </parent>
    <groupId>isi.code</groupId>
    <artifactId>secure-demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>secure-demo</name>
    <description>secure-demo</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>21</java.version>
        <spring-security.version>6.2.1</spring-security.version>
        <spring.version>6.1.2</spring.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.persistence-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Clean, install, compile with Maven doesnt give me any Errors.
antMatchers() was replaced with reqeustMatchers() and javax was replace with jakarta.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Don't... Just upgrade to Spring BOot 3.2 which includes the proper version, don't start ixing incompatible Spring versions into a Spring Boot version.

Comment: https://spring.io/blog/2023/12/21/spring-boot-3-2-1-available-now/

Comment: ok. Thank you both. I thought it would be good pratice to learn more about how spring works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As adviced, I should upgrade to Spring boot 3.2.

https://spring.io/blog/2023/12/21/spring-boot-3-2-1-available-now/

Comment: @wotanii yes, sorry i had to wait until i could mark it solved.